# Issue finding $F$ (distribution function) given $f$ (density function)

Tags: probability

$X$ is a random variable with density function

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
c(1-x^2) &\mbox{if }-1 < x < 1 \\
0 &\mbox{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

The problem statement requires us to find $c$ and consequently find $F$. I found $c = \frac{3}{2}$ by setting up the integral $\int_{0}^{1}c(1-x^2)dx = 1$ and solving for $c$.

My issue starts when trying to find the distribution function $F$.

I used the definition in my textbook: $F_X(t) = \int_{-\infty}^{t}f_X(x)dx$.

Because of the piecewise nature of $f$, we would have 2 cases:

$t\leq -1$: $\int_{-\infty}^{t}0dx = 0$

$t > -1$: This is the case that confuses me. I compute the integral $\int_{-\infty}^{t} \frac{3}{2}(1-x^2)dx$ and get $-\infty$. This doesn't seem right to me. Where did I go wrong?

EDIT: I suspect that I should actually set up the second integral as $\int_{-1}^{t} \frac{3}{2}(1-x^2)dx$ instead.

Comment: For starters, you should solve for $c$ in $\int_{-1}^1 c(1-x^2)\,\mathrm dx=1$.

Comment: Ah yeah, thank you. All of my previous problems assumed only nonnegative values for $x$, so I was in a habit.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your suspicion is correct. The density function $f_X(x)$ is equal to $0$ if $x\not\in(-1,1)$. Hence,
$$
F_X(t)=\int_{-\infty}^tf_X(x)\mathrm dx=\int_{-\infty}^{-1}f_X(x)\mathrm dx+\int_{-1}^tf_X(x)\mathrm dx=\int_{-1}^tf_X(x)\mathrm dx=c\int_{-1}^t1-x^2\mathrm dx
$$
for $-1\le t\le1$.

Comment: Thank you! This is so much clearer than my text.

Comment: @stassp You're welcome!